# How to implement AfterEffects Animation in Android App (using Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, animation

First of all: I'm new in Appdevelopment.

I want to put an Animation into my App. It's an AfterEffects Animation, I think it will be a .json-file. I have no idea how to do that and haven't found something useful in the internet.

I **don't** want to animate a text or picture with the Animations-API (like rotate something).

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to create animations yourself, then you'd need Adobe AfterEffects and Bodymovin Plugin which renders the animations into many formats , out of which .json format is usually preferred for simple animations.
You can visit [Android Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) and get some information on how to integrate simple animations to your android application.

**Lottie animations can load animations from:**

A json animation in src/main/res/raw.
A json file in src/main/assets.
A zip file in src/main/assets. See images docs for more info.
A url to a json or zip file.
A json string. The source can be from anything including your own network stack.
An InputStream to either a json file or a zip file.

**From XML**

From res/raw (lottie_rawRes) or assets/ (lottie_fileName)

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/hello_world"
    // or
    app:lottie_fileName="hello_world.json"

    // Loop indefinitely
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    // Start playing as soon as the animation is loaded
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true" />
```

For further documentaion and help, visit [**here**](http://airbnb.io/lottie/android/android.html)